# TortoiseSVN Update a repo from an unversioned folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to clean up a mess I've found. A significant amount of work for a project has been done in an unversioned folder on a computer, and I want to make TortoiseSVN recognize that folder as an SVN repo so I can upload the changes to the repo. Is this possible or will I need to check out the repo and copy all of my changes? Ideally, I'd like to avoid this because of bandwidth restrictions on the machine in question.

Comment: Repository or a working copy?

Comment: A repository. As of now, there is nothing checked out from this repo on the machine in question.